# Proof no DPDA can accept Palindrome (need explanation for the attached proof)

Tags: finite-automata, pushdown-automata

The given proof for proving that no DPDA can be constructed to accept palindromes is unclear. There exists another similar question but it only explains the proof partially.

I understood how it aims to find two strings r and s (r!=s) for which rz,and sz with a common suffix z will be processed in the exact same way by a hypothetical DPDA.

However, how is it possible to find such strings if the DPDA doesn't exist at all?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The proof is quite long. Is there any particular part you are having difficulty with?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It says that finding two strings rz and sz (r!=s) which will lead to the same processing by M is sufficient to prove. How do we find such r and s?

Comment: This is explained in the final paragraph (*Now we are ready to choose the strings $r$ and $s$.*)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes that's the unclear part for me

Comment: We are a question-and-answer site.  We require you to articulate a *specific* question about your situation. Asking us to explain the entire proof is too much for an answer here.  And, I worry you might tell us you didn't understand that explanation, either.  Give us something to work with by telling us what parts you did understand, and what was the first line you didn't understand, and what your understanding of that line is, and then articulate a specific question about that line.

Comment: @D.W. I've updated it to the precise part which is confusing to me

Comment: The image is from: **John C. Martin, Introduction to Languages and the Theory of Computation, 2010**. Although the book (very unfortunately) is out of print for quite some time now, it seems appropriate to acknowledge the source.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).  If you're not familiar with proof by contradiction, I suggest learning about that proof method (and more generally, refreshing your knowledge of discrete mathematics and proof techniques) before trying to understand this specific proof.

You can think of it this way: either $M$ exists, or it doesn't.  If $M$ does exist, you can find strings $r,s$ with a property that leads to a contradiction -- so we can conclude that it's not actually possible for $M$ to exist.  The only remaining possibility is that $M$ does not exist.

Comment: Yes I'm able to realize that the author wants to prove by contradiction that such M cannot exist. However, in the process, I'm unable to grasp how he wants us to select r and s which will lead to such contradiction. More specifically, how is the result after processing rz and sz same for the considered M.

Comment: @Mdit, well, that's a different question than the one you asked in your post.  This site isn't designed for interactive tutoring or back-and-forths.